# Deleting old winform and tray icon when I make a new winform

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I have two winforms. The first acts as my control panel and the second I use to take screen shots. However, when I go from Winform 2 back to Winform 1 I have a new winform created and a brand new tray icon. This is on top of the initial ones I create when the program first starts.

When I go from winform 1 to winform 2 I do the following:

```
 this.Hide();
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
 form2.InstanceRef = this;
 form2.Show();
```

Then when I want to go back from Winform 2 to Winform 1 I do the following:

```
 this.Close();
 Winform1 form;
 form = new Winform1 (capturedImageObj);
 form.Show();
```

I know straight off the bat the issue falls on the fact I'm creating a new Winform1, but I need to do that so I can pass my capturedImageObj back into Winform 1.

I've tried calling `this.close()` and `this.dispose()` in the my first section of code but that only closes the program down. Is there a way I can dispose of Winform 1 but still use Winform 2 and pass the object I need to back into a new copy of Winform 1?

Here is the constructor for my Winform 1:

```
public ControlPanel(Image imjObj)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
   _screenCap.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;
   capturedImage = imjObj;
   imagePreview.Image = capturedImage;
}
```

Comment: Does it work as expected when capturedImageObj is not passed to Winform1 ?

Comment: Why not create a custom event in winform2, and then subscribe to it in Winform1. Or you can listen for Winform2's FormClosing Event, add a Method to Winform2 the exposes the image and get from Winform2 in the FormClosing EventHandler

Comment: capturedImageObj is part of my constructor for Winform1 I need to have something displayed in my first winform. I'll update with my constructor code

Comment: Mark - I already use a custom event to get the captured image across. Are you suggesting I close Winform 1 from that event in Winform 2? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: No, I wasn't, Just looking at your Constructor code you posted, I don't see anything that precludes you from using the same Form. I would take your _screenCap definition out of the constructor, and move the rest into one of the methods that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Winform1 to use properties like this:

```
public Image CapturedImage {
   get { return imagePreview.Image; }
   set { imagePreview.Image = value; }
}
```

Then change your constructor like this:

```
public ControlPanel(Image imjObj)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
   _screenCap.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;
    CapturedImage = imjObj;
}
```

And, finally, change your Winform2 to do this:

```
((Winform1)this.InstanceRef).CapturedImage = capturedImageObj;
this.InstanceRef.Show();
this.Close();
```

---

Based on the comment, it sounds like your `InstanceRef` property is of type `Form`. Change it to be of type `Winform1`. Or, I changed the code above to do some casting for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I had an error with this.InstanceRef.CapturedImage. My program is saying there is no definition for it even though I put the get and set in my winform1 like you suggested. Is there something else I need to do?